# Less verbose alternatives to passing a smart pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, coding-style, smart-pointers

We all know and love smart pointers for their safety and speed, but having to call functions like this bugs me out:

```
void TreeNode::addChild(unique_ptr<TreeNode> newChild){
    children_.push_back(std::move(newChild));
}
//This has to be called like so:

node.addChild(unique_ptr<TreeNode>(new TreeNode(10));
```

I find it to be unnecessarily verbose and long. Is this really the best way to do things? Can't I just pass a raw pointer and create my `unique_ptr` inside of `addChild`? What are alternatives and what are the benefits of this verbosity?

**EDIT:** I wanted to add that `TreeNode` can be derived from, so just implementing `addChild(int arg)` isn't quite enough. But

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You may do the following:

  ```
  template<typename...Ts>
  void TreeNode::emplaceChild(Ts&&...args){
      children_.emplace_back(make_unique<TreeNode>(std::forward<Ts>(args)...));
  }
  ```

  And then:

  ```
  node.emplaceChild(10);
  ```
- To specify the Type of child to add, you may use as replacement:

  ```
  template<typename T, typename...Ts>
  void TreeNode::emplaceChild(Ts&&...args) {
      children_.emplace_back(make_unique<T>(std::forward<Ts>(args)...));
  }
  ```

  And then:

  ```
  node.emplaceChild<TreeNode>(10);
  ```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I want to be able to subclass TreeNode, sorry. But this is the best looking answer so far!

Comment: I don't think you need an `emplace_back` there.

Comment: this is really strange syntax, I can't seem to get my head around it quite yet...

Comment: ok, I edited an easier example in to your answer and accepted it, it certainly helped me a lot! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

In C++14 you can use [`std::make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) function.

In C++11 implement it yourself, e.g.:

```
#include <memory>

struct X { X(int, int); };

void foo(std::unique_ptr<X>);

template<class T, class... Args>
inline std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args&&... args) {
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}

int main() {
    foo(make_unique<X>(1, 2));
}
```

Comment: That alleviates only slightly the verbosity in the call and doesn't even touch the verbosity in the function declaration and definition. Remember that the comparison should be with plain new in the call and a raw pointer in the declaration.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: from the original question: _... having to call functions like this bugs me out ..._

Comment: Of course, you can also overload `addChild` from the question using  `template<class... Args> void TreeNode::addChild(Args&&... args)`, inn effect inlining `std::make_unique`. Result: `node.addChild(10)`.

Comment: @MatteoItalia I don't really care about the function definition or declaration being verbose, I only do those once and I can comment them as much as I want. But the call to it should be short and clear.
One thing I *do* like about this solution is that the call to `foo` has no ambiguous parts but is clear in the fact that a unique pointer is passed.

Comment: @MSalters this is a very cool idea, but then again I could just pass the argument and create the object inside of addChild. Unfortunately though, TreeNode can be subclassed so that's not really an option. I was thinking about passing the type and the constructor-argument to `addChild`, but I'm not sure about how I could implement that. (I made something like this with enums, but that seems overcomplicated)

Comment: @iFreilicht `tree.emplaceChild<X>(args...);`

Comment: I never tried function templating before, but this looks just like the solution. I'll search for a source about that, but feel free to point me to a good one you know :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `typedef` (which is replaced by `using` in C++11):

```
using TreeNodeUP = std::unique_ptr<TreeNode>;
```

to simplify some code:

```
void TreeNode::addChild(TreeNodeUP newChild);
```

An alternative, if you have control over the type `TreeNode` is to put the `typedef` inside the class and call it `UP` or something similarly short and use

```
void TreeNode::addChild(TreeNode::UP newChild);
```

Note that I personally don't like those `typedef`s, I prefer the more verbose version of spelling out `std::unique_ptr` and I haven't really found it to be a real problem.

Comment: I quite like me some typedefs, but this seems to reduce the declaration/definition verbosity, not the one in the call which was more what I'm aiming for. Verbosity in definitions is nice for self-documentation reasons, and I only have to write them once.